# No NSLog output in terminal from tests run with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, terminal, continuous-integration, xctest, xcodebuild

I am trying to implement CI on ios. I am running xcode unit tests from commandline using xcodebuild on a real device (iPad):

```
xcodebuild test -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme tests DEVELOPMENT_TEAM={DEV_TEAM_ID} -destination platform=iOS,id={DEVICE_UUID} build-for-testing -allowProvisioningUpdates -configuration {Debug/Release}
```

I've got a single unit test which contains NSLog calls inside. The problem is that those logs are not displayed in the terminal window in which xcodebuild was called:

```
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2018-06-07 05:10:45.653
Test Suite 'XcodeTests.xctest' started at 2018-06-07 05:10:45.655
Test Suite 'XcodeTests.xctest' failed at 2018-06-07 05:10:45.655.
        Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.00) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2018-06-07 05:10:45.656.
        Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected in 0.00 (0.003) seconds
```

I've looked into the device logs from Xcode's `Window->Devices and Simulators-> View Device Logs` and it looks like they are there but as Notice (perhaps the fact that they are Notice matters):

```
Jun  7 05:10:45 MyiPad tests(XcodeTests)[21982] <Notice>: ENTERED TEST
Jun  7 05:10:45 MyiPad tests[21982] <Notice>: CREATED EXPECTATIONS
```

I've tested this launching method on another mac with another attached iPad and it strangely works. The configuration from the machine on which it worked to display the NSLog messages in the terminal is the following:

```
 System Software Overview:

 System Version: macOS 10.13.2 (17C88)
 Kernel Version: Darwin 17.3.0
 Boot Volume: SYSTEM
 Boot Mode: Normal
 Computer Name: Mac001
 User Name: MacUser001
 Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
 System Integrity Protection: Enabled
 Time since boot: 7 days 48 minutes

 XCODE VERSION DETAILS: 
 Xcode 9.2
 Build version 9C40b

 Device iOS Version: 11.2 (15C114)
```

The other configuration on which it doesn't show the NSLogs in the terminal is the following:

```
System Software Overview:

System Version: macOS 10.13.3 (17D47)
Kernel Version: Darwin 17.4.0
Boot Volume: SYSTEM
Boot Mode: Normal
Computer Name: Mac002
User Name: MacUser002
Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
System Integrity Protection: Enabled
Time since boot: 7 days 48 minutes

XCODE VERSION DETAILS: 
Xcode 9.2
Build version 9C40b

Device iOS Version: 10.2 (14C92)
```

What could be the problem? Could it be from the device or the mac workstation? (I don't have physical access to any of them, just remote to the mac).

Comment: I encountered the same problem. And finally, I use printf instead NSLog. printf works well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed for iOS versions 10+, it looks like the NSLog is treated like a < Notice > message and is not included in the stdout or stderr outputted by xcodebuild. I found that out by looking into the device console log.
I found the solution that devliubo mentioned a while ago, but I wasn't sure if this is a common issue (thanks devliubo).
Using printf instead of NSLog is the only way to print the messages for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dan said, if you want to see the message in your test being printed on the console you better use `printf` and not `NSLog`

Example  `printf("%s", [yourNSString UTF8String]);`